# How to fix error with Unsupported image type on Image::make

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-6

I'm trying to create images/user_avatars with Laravel Nova admin panel and with api. I need generate 3 pictures for each download - avatar, thumbnail and preview.

```php
 public function fields(Request $request)
     {
          return [

       //some fields else
        Avatar::make(__('Profile Photo'), 'avatar_path')
             ->path('images/users/avatars')
             ->storeAs(function (Request $request){
                 $file = $request->file('avatar_path');
                 return $request->user()->id.'_'. sha1($file->getClientOriginalName()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
             })
            ->preview(function ($value, $disk){
                 return $this->getCroppedAvatar($value, 'prev', 636);
             })
             ->thumbnail(function ($value, $disk){
                 return $this->getCroppedAvatar($value, 'thumb', 64);
             })
             ->disableDownload(),
```

In this field i'm using the following method

```php
     public static function getCroppedAvatar($value, $type, $size)
         {
              $path = str_replace('avatars', $type , $value);
              if ($value && !Storage::exists($value)) {
                  return null;
              }
              if ($value && is_file(Storage::path($path)) && !is_dir(Storage::path($path))) {
             return Storage::url($path);
              }
              if ($value) {
                 Image::make(Storage::path($value))
                   ->widen($size)->save(Storage::path($path));
                  Log::info('New preview is ' . Storage::path($path));
                  return Storage::url($path);
              }
              return null;
          }
```

In this case Laravel Nova is working, but if I try to call getCroppedAvatar from API Controller, i have an error on Image::make line:

```
Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF or WebP files. {"userId":16,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException(code: 0): Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF or WebP files. at /var/www/tracker/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php:59)
```

Code on API Controller

```php
    Storage::put($fileDirectory.'/'.$fileName, $image);
    User::getCroppedAvatar($fileDirectory.'/'.$fileName,'prev', 636);
    User::getCroppedAvatar($fileDirectory.'/'.$fileName,'thumb', 64);
```

In both cases i'm using png and jpg files. Argument values are the same. 
How can i fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i found solution. As i understand, Storage class creating not correct type of image, so i changed this line from API Controller

```
Storage::put($fileDirectory.'/'.$fileName, $image);
```

for this:

```
Image::make($file)->save(Storage::path($filePath));
```